# Forwards and return type(s) in functional-like reduce function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, temporary

I need to create a `reduce` function similar to [`std::reduce`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce), but instead of working on containers, this function should work on variadic parameters.

This is what I currently have:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) reduce(F&&, T &&t) {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template <typename F, typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) reduce(F&& f, T1&& t1, T2&& t2, Args&&... args) {
    return reduce(
        std::forward<F>(f),
        std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2)),
        std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The following works as expected:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
decltype(auto) u = reduce([](auto &a, auto b) -> auto& {
        std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
        return a;
    }, vec, std::set<int>{1, 2}, std::list<int>{3, 4}, std::vector<int>{5, 6});

assert(&vec == &u); // ok
assert(vec == std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}); // ok
```

But the following does not work:

```
auto u = reduce([](auto a, auto b) {
        std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
        return a;
    }, std::vector<int>{}, std::set<int>{1, 2}, 
    std::list<int>{3, 4}, std::vector<int>{5, 6});
```

This basically crashes - To make this work, I need to e.g. change the first definition of `reduce` to:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
constexpr auto reduce(F&&, T &&t) {
    return t;
}
```

But if I do so, the first snippet does not work anymore.

The problem problem lies in the forwarding of the parameters and the return type of the `reduce` function, but I can find it.

How should I modify my `reduce` definitions to make both snippets work?

Comment: Have a look at C++17 folding expressions http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
template <typename F, typename T>
constexpr T reduce(F&&, T &&t) {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

This returns a prvalue when the second argument was an rvalue, and an lvalue referring to the argument otherwise. Your snippets seem to be [fine with it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28e3c7c4ee7ce807).

Alternatively, just use your second variant and wrap `vec` in `std::ref`, mutatis mutandis. That is also the standard approach when templates handle objects by value.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is strong magic, one must be extremely careful that you actually *mean* it.  +1

Answer (score 2):

The lambda in your problem case:

```
[](auto a, auto b) {
    std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
    return a;
}
```

returns by value, so when `reduce` recurses:

```
 return reduce(
    std::forward<F>(f),
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2)), // HERE
    std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

The second argument is a temporary initialized from that by-value return object. When the recursion finally terminates:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) reduce(F&&, T &&t) {
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

It returns a reference bound to that temporary object which is destroyed while unwinding the recursion, so that `v` is initialized from a dangling reference.

The easiest fix for this would be to NOT create a temporary in your lambda and instead accumulate the results in the input object which you know will live at least until the end of the full expression ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b05341ccb37224ab)):

```
auto fn = [](auto&& a, auto const& b) -> decltype(auto) {
    std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
    // Or better:
    // a.insert(std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::end(b));
    return static_cast<decltype(a)>(a);
};

std::vector<int> vec;
decltype(auto) u = reduce(fn, vec,
    std::set<int>{1, 2}, std::list<int>{3, 4}, std::vector<int>{5, 6});

assert(&vec == &u); // ok
assert((vec == std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})); // ok

auto v = reduce(fn, std::vector<int>{},
    std::set<int>{1, 2},  std::list<int>{3, 4}, std::vector<int>{5, 6});
assert((v == std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})); // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned fold expressions.

```
template<class F, class T=void>
struct reduce_t;

template<class F>
reduce_t<F> reduce( F&& f );

template<class F, class T>
reduce_t<F, T> reduce( F&& f, T&& t );

template<class F, class T>
struct reduce_t {
  F f;
  T t;
  template<class Rhs>
  auto operator|( Rhs&& rhs )&&{
    return reduce( f, f( std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) ) );
  }
  T get()&&{ return std::forward<T>(t); }
};
template<class F>
struct reduce_t<F,void> {
  F f;
  template<class Rhs>
  auto operator|( Rhs&& rhs )&&{
    return reduce( f, std::forward<Rhs>(rhs) );
  }
};

template<class F>
reduce_t<F> reduce( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}

template<class F, class T>
reduce_t<F, T> reduce( F&& f, T&& t ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(t)};
}
template<class F, class T, class...Ts>
auto reduce( F&& f, T&& t, Ts&&...ts ) {
    return (reduce( std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<T>(t) ) | ... |  std::forward<Ts>(ts));
}
```

then any of these work:

```
decltype(auto) u = (reduce([](auto &a, auto b) -> auto& {
    std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
    return a;
}) | vec | std::set<int>{1, 2} | std::list<int>{3, 4} | std::vector<int>{5, 6}).get();

decltype(auto) u = reduce([](auto &a, auto b) -> auto& {
    std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
    return a;
}, vec, std::set<int>{1, 2}, std::list<int>{3, 4}, std::vector<int>{5, 6}).get();

auto u_val = (
    reduce([](auto a, auto b) {
      std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::back_inserter(a));
      return a;
    })
    | std::vector<int>{} | std::set<int>{1, 2}
    | std::list<int>{3, 4} | std::vector<int>{5, 6}
).get();
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/324b00b369a0de1e).